# Prevent Internet Explorer tabs from opening tabs in stack in taskbar

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, taskbar, tabs

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate, and IE 8, and have the taskbar in icon view. I'm not sure how to explain this, but I'm amazed at how each tab in IE8 seems to act like a new "thing" in the taskbar (as if each tab was a window).

Each tab acts like a different window in the taskbar although they are actually running in the same window. Now when I use IE 8 it looks (in the taskbar) like there's 15 windows open when in fact the taskbar is simply showing the 15 tabs.

[image: Tabs displayed in stack]

More simply put, it's displaying a "stack" for all of the tabs when I'd rather have the icon act like, for example, Firefox so that a stack is only shown for the multiple windows.

Is there a way to disable this strange "taskbar" effect? I'd rather have the taskbar show the main window and not the tabs individually.

There has to be a simple way to do this.

Comment: Ironically, some people criticizes Firefox for not showing the tabs as individual processes on the taskbar like IE8, which means you can’t see the open pages without switching to the browser. :)

Comment: @Leonardo: The task bar doesn't care about *processes* there. It cares about windows belonging to similar processes and you can make that distinction for your own as a developer (for MDI or tabbed interfaces for example).

Comment: Thanks, Johannes, I didn't use the right word (I said _processes_ to match the language of the question.)

Comment: Ah... I should probably change the language of the question.

Comment: @Leonardo You can enable and disable this in FF, just as you can in MSIE.

Comment: @Vervious Sometimes, knowing how to ask a question can be more difficult than answering it. :-)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

See "[How to Disable IE8/IE9 Tab previews in Windows 7 taskbar](http://webtrickz.com/how-to-disable-ie8-tab-previews-in-windows-7-taskbar/)"

> To disable IE tab previews in taskbar,
>   just open **Internet Explorer > Tools >
>   Internet Options.** Open settings for
>   ‘**Tabs**’ and uncheck the box saying
>   ‘**Show previews for individual tabs in
>   the taskbar**’. Click Ok and restart IE
>   for letting changes to take effect.

<sub>(The **Tabs** settings are opened via a button in the **General** tab of **Internet Options**)</sub>

This solution works for Internet Explorer versions 8 through 11.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Such a simple solution. I probably should have Googled a bit more before on asking on SU. :)

Comment: Nah... asking it here is the point so that it helps SU grow and helps everyone like me who comes here first to look for answers. It solved my problem; +1 for the question and for the answer.

Comment: Works for Internet Explorer 9 too.

Comment: This still works 4 years later in IE11 (under Windows 7 at least anyway). :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Confirmed however it's worth noting the asterisk (following the checkbox label) that's used to infer the computer needs to be restarted. This is inaccurate on IE's part. I only had to click apply and restart the browser (not the computer).

Comment: Can confirm this works in IE8, IE9, IE10, and IE11.