# Prevent a single IE window with multiple open tabs from being displayed as multiple windows in the taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-8, internet-explorer, taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent IE8 tabs from opening tabs in stack in taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/131146/prevent-ie8-tabs-from-opening-tabs-in-stack-in-taskbar)

When I use IE 9 or 10, and open multiple tabs, the taskbar icon is shown like there are many instances of IE, even though it's only one window. This happens in both Windows 7 and 8. I am asking this because it frustrates me to have to click the taskbar icon, and then have to click on either tab, instead of just clicking the icon in the taskbar and let IE maximize, showing me the last tab I was viewing. Can this be changed?

Comment: Apparently this issue and its solution has been around since IE8 see [Prevent IE8 tabs from opening tabs in stack in taskbar](http://superuser.com/q/131146/42881)

Comment: @ConradFrix I've never even given IE8 an chance, so I didn't know :D  I always type my questions slowly, just in case something similar pops up, but nothing showed up- so, I asked.

Comment: I totally understand. In fact I only found it by looking for "Show previews for individual tabs in the taskbar" which means you had to know the answer in order to find it. On the other had IE 12 users with Windows 9 might actually might find this question because it has a better title ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The setting to change the tab behavior is **Show previews for individual tabs in the taskbar**:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> in Internet Explorer to get to Internet options.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or press the <kbd>Tabs</kbd> button about halfway down on the **General** tab.
3. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> will toggle the setting. You can select and clear the check box with your mouse.
4. Click **OK** twice.

Alternatively:

1. Click **Tools** (gear) icon on the right of Internet Explorer window.
2. Click **Internet options**.
3. Click **Settings** button in **Tabs** group (at the bottom of **General** tab).
4. Clear **Show previews for individual tabs in the taskbar** check box.
5. Click **OK** twice.

[image: Tabbed Browsing Setting]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you @Patrick!

Comment: works, required restart of browser